# firefox 31 the javascript submit not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, form-submit

problem with firefox 31 as the javascript submit not working. the problem arises at     product page as after selecting the product it is not navigating to the cart page or wishlist page. i have tested it on other browsers and also on firefox 30 and it works fine on them. I have also tried to disable other plugins but it didnt work. I debug the below given code snippet and its variable are getting desired values as per the logic for instance it is entering the else only when the user has checked the field.  I will be grateful for the any quick solutions.

```
    echo "<input class=\"button wish_btn_style\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to   
    wishlist\" onclick=\"return changelocation('wishlist.php')\"><!--img   
    src=\"img/wishlist_small.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"15\"-->";
    echo "<input class=\"button cart_btn_style\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to cart\" 
    onclick=\"return changelocation('cart.php')\"><!--img src=\"img/cart_gray.png\" 
    width=\"32\" height=\"24\"-->";

function changelocation(action)
{var canigo=0;
   var x=document.getElementById('txt_quent').value;
   var status;
 if((x=="") || isNaN(x))
 {
  alert("Please enter quantity only in number");
  var canigo=1;
  return false;
    }

    if(canigo==0)
        {status=$('input:radio[name="subid"]:checked').val();
    if(isNaN(status))
    {

     alert('Please select the desired product specification');
        return false;   
    }
    else
    {

         document.getElementById('product').action=action;
        document.getElementById('product').target='_self';
        document.getElementById('product').submit();


        return true;  

    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: What is `document.getElementById('product').action` before this script runs?  Similar for `target`?

Comment: the action attribute is getting its value as per the submit button if user clicks Add to cart then action will be cart.php and if user clicks add to wishlist the action will be wishlist.php

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question.  The question was whether `document.getElementById('product').action` is a string before this code runs or whether it's an element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an input field in your form named 'action' by any chance?

I experienced a bug with some old code today in Firefox 31. In previous versions of Firefox, .action resolved to the 'action' attribute of the form, but in version 31 it has changed to resolve to an input field named 'action' on the page instead.

I got it working again by using jQuery:

```
$("#defForm").attr("action", sURL);
```

Alternatively, I could have changed the input field naming convention used on the page.

I would be interested to understand the reason for the change in Firefox's behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Solved my case in final post.

I have the same problem, but I use a input action and it's a big problem to change the name of input for me.

This script is ok on previous version of Firefox 31.

```
if(ie){
    for(i=document.getElementById('miForm').attributes.length-1;i>0;i--){
        if(document.getElementById('miForm').attributes[i].name=='action'){
            document.getElementById('miForm').attributes[i].value='../views/newJSP.jsp';
            break;
        }
    }
}else document.getElementById('miForm').action='../views/newJSP.jsp';
document.getElementById('action').value='abrir';
document.getElementById('miForm').submit();
```

On Firefox in if(ie) no return any attribute with the name action, when in previous versions it's return action attribute.

I haven't any solution.

edit:
it's a bug?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.action

SOLUTION:

My script have an error in for loop.
In ie, the length of attributes in form is 116 and action attribute is in position 114, but in firefox, the length is 5 and action is in position 0.

This is code for update form.action.

```
for(i=document.getElementById('miForm').attributes.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(document.getElementById('miForm').attributes[i].name=='action'){
        document.getElementById('miForm').attributes[i].value='../views/newJSP.jsp';
        break;
    }
}
```